# What does the “+2” and “:” in [:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+2]mean in this code?

Tags: python

Why in the first case its "+2" while below its "+4:"?

```
def get_http_headers(http_payload):
    try:
        # split the headers off if it is HTTP traffic
        headers_raw = http_payload[:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+2]

        # break out the headers
        headers = dict(re.findall(r"(?P<name>.*?): (?P<value>.*?)\r\n", headers_raw))

    except:
        return None

    return headers

def extract_image(headers, http_payload):
    image = None
    image_type = None

    try:
        if "image" in headers["Content-Type"]:
            # grab the image type and image body
            image_type = headers["Content-Type"].split("/")[1]

            image = http_payload[http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+4:]
```

Comment: the `.index` resolves to a number. the +2 is literally just adding 2 to it. (btw, `\r` is 1 character. so is `\n`. Can you figure out why the addition is being done?)

Comment: Tagging both `python-2.7` and `python-3.x` adds no information to your question.

Comment: Thank you!
Can you give me an example of what it does or what the output would be @ParitoshSingh ? And what about ":" in [:http_payload.index ? whats the difference between [:http_payload.index and [http_payload.index?

Comment: One question per question, please...

Comment: Alas, it's doubtful that anyone will tell you that without knowing what is http_payload. Reading about lists splicing will help you understand those ":".

Answer (score 0):

The call to `http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")` returns the starting index of the first blank line in the string `http_payload`, and `http_payload[:index]` slices the string `http_payload` up to the given index, so `http_payload[:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+2]` returns `http_payload` sliced up to the first blank line, but with the first of the two `\r\n`s included, i.e. a trailing newline, since the index plus two includes the two characters past the starting index of `\r\n\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

The "`http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")`" part means, "Look for the string `\r\n\r\n` inside of the value of `http_payload`, and get the position number were it first shows up."  Or, if `http_payload` is a list, then it means find the position within the list where the value there is `\r\n\r\n`.  So the `+2` simply adds two to this value. Effectively, what you're doing here is, "Look for where there's a double-spaced line, and find the position of where the second line break in that pair is."

So the full `http_payload[:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+2]` command means, "Take the string, look for the first double-spaced line break, and chop off anything from that second line break onward."

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at it this way.

Save the index value to a variable first. The index value is likely to be an integer:

```
http_payload_index = http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n") #resolves to an integer value
```

In the first case, the attempt is to add 2 to the above value and with string slicing select everything upto `http_payload_index+2` position:

```
headers_raw = http_payload[:http_payload_index+2]
```

So, for example, if `http_payload_index` equals 3, then 3+2=5 would give:

```
headers_raw = http_payload[:5]
```

And if `http_payload` consists of a string like `'This is a header'`, then `headers_raw` will evaluate to `'This '`, selecting everything upto index position 5.

Similarly, in the second case :

```
headers_raw = http_payload[http_payload_index+4:]
```

If `http_payload_index` is 3, then `headers_raw` will evaluate to 3+4=7 and

`headers_raw = http_payload[7:]` and if `http_payload` consists of the same string `This is a header`, then `headers_raw` will evaluate to `' a header'`, selecting everything from index position 7.

You can read more about string slicing [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)